# Fetch remaining data on last page in pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm making a simple pagination for the comments on the projects i'm working on. But i have an issue where i can keep requesting more comments and get a blank page.

My API URL for fetching comments is: `{{URL}}/responses?id={{id}}&skip={{skip}}&take=10`

```
  nextComments = () => {
    if (this.state.skip <= this.state.responses.total) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        skip: prevState.skip + 
      }), async () => {
        const responsesbyId = await getResponsesbyOrgId(this.state.orgId, this.state.skip);
  
        this.setState({
          responses: responsesbyId
        })
  
        console.log(this.state.responses);
      });
    }
  };
```

I've tried setting a max, but then an another issue is that when there is e.g. 16 comments i can skip 10 then 10 more and end up with a blank page again.

Is there a smarter way to deal with this? so i round up to 6 when there is less than 10 comments left?

hope i'm clear in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have control over your backend based on the question, so ideally, this is something your API should make the front end aware of. The API should return the **total** number of results from a query, as well as the number of results per page and what page you're currently viewing (starts at 1). Then the front end can look at those values and dynamically control the pagination logic.

So for example, API response could be something like:

```
const res = {
  results: [...],
  resultCount: 16,
  page: 1,
  resultsPerPage: 10
};
```

(you'd be storing the current page in the front end state of course, but just added it to the backend response since it usually doesn't hurt to return the request params).

Then in your front end, where you're storing the current page value, the logic could be

```
if ((currentPage * resultsPerPage) < resultCount) { /* You can let them fetch another page */}
```

This would satisfy your requirements of not letting them view more pages if they shouldn't be able to, and also lets the results per page variable change in the backend without the front end having to do a thing.

Comment: The API returns `{total: 52, skip: 0, take: 10, results: Array(6)}`. No idea why it's made in that way but you skip the amount and take the amount you want and that is how they used to change page in Angular. I'm rewriting it in React.

Comment: Well you should be able to do it if you're tracking the current page on the front end. It'd just be `(currentPage * take) < total --> they can fetch another batch`

Comment: How would one go and track the currentPage? do i divide the total with take and math ceil that?

Comment: Well no you just track it in real time. When they first load data, page is 1. If they go forward/backward a page, you increment/decrement current page number respectively. If they go to a certain page, you set that to the current page number. Shouldn't require any special maths or anything

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation!